# Tensorflow how to increment the dimension of variable

Tags: tensorflow

When we do tf.embedding_lookup, it returns a vector (not matrix).

```
In [244]: one_hot_label = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(np.eye(vocab_size), Y[labels_i])

In [245]: one_hot_label
Out[245]: <tf.Tensor 'embedding_lookup_43975:0' shape=(20, 8000) dtype=float64>
```

I need to reshape this `(20,8000)` tensor into `(20,8000,1)`. How should I do it? 
I'm not asking for hard-cord (20,8000,1) using tf.reshape. I'm asking in general how to convert 2d -> 3d or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims): this operation inserts a dimension of 1 into the tensor's shape.

```
one_hot_label = tf.expand_dims(one_hot_label, axis=2)
```